# Stringtokenizer undefined

Tags: java, constructor, undefined, stringtokenizer

Hi i got some problem making a stringtokenizer method which allow string input by user and count and print tokens. Can someone help me solve error? It says the constructor is undefined.

```
public class StringTokenizer
{
  public static void main(String[ ] args)
  {
      Scanner keyboard;
      String inputSentence;
      StringTokenizer stok = null; //declare a reference to hold the address of a StringTokenizer object
      keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a line of text: ");
      inputSentence = new String(keyboard.nextLine( ) );
      while(!(inputSentence.equals("quit")))
      {
          stok = new StringTokenizer(inputSentence);//the constructor that take a String and uses a space as the delimeter
          while (stok.hasMoreTokens());
          {
          System.out.println("Number of tokens: " + stok.countTokens( ));
          System.out.println(stok.nextToken( ));
          }




        System.out.println("Enter another line of data or quit\n" );
        inputSentence = keyboard.nextLine( );

    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye");



    }//end of main
} //end of class
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks for telling me the other error i forgot to list it as well. And yes the compiler says the errors was the constructor one in first place, I don't what constructor suppose to be with this as I remembered my professor said I only have to declare instance since the class is already in java.util package. I made another one with different class name to make it less confused and also imported java.util, the errors still happen. Can you help me with the constructor thing?

Answer (score 3):

Rename **your** class. You are shadowing `java.util.StringTokenizer`; alternatively,

```
java.util.StringTokenizer stok = null;
```

**and**

```
stok = new java.util.StringTokenizer(inputSentence);
```

**But**, it'll be less confusing if you rename your class.

Comment: Agreed. It’s never a good idea to name your class the same as any class anywhere under the `java` package.

Comment: I made another class with different name, and also import java.util.*; the error still happens do you know why?

Comment: @DavePhan You didn't remove the existing class in the current package with the name `StringTokenizer` (and thus you are still **shadowing** it).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I actually made the 2nd one on a different laptop and i also change the class name on the first one as well. The prior error said to be for the constructor but I have no idea what it is

Comment: *The prior error said to be for the constructor* What is the new error?

Comment: there's also errors on hasMoreTokens and nextToken as well, it's not new tho. I thought it's linked up to the constructor error so I forgot to mention in the post but @Carcigenicate reminded me that.